# Please help porting xmlrpc java syntax to python

Tags: java, python, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I'm trying to workout how to use org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient in python.

I'm using code in https://github.com/mcasperson/vaultdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/redhat/ecs/App.java :

```
final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL(args[0]));
config.setBasicUserName(args[1]);
config.setBasicPassword(args[2]);

final XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
client.setConfig(config);

final Object[] params = new Object[] {"1376"};
final String retValue = (String) client.execute("ContentAPI.queryResult", params);
```

I was trying following python code, but I'm not getting anywhere:

```
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy
s = ServerProxy(url)
print s.client.execute("ContentAPI.queryResult",1376)
```

What how do I pass the username and password to python's ServerProxy client?

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be a good idea to read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) of the library you're trying to use.

This might work ... possibly:

```
import xmlrpclib

conn_settings = \
{
    "user" : "noob",
    "pass" : "1234",
    "host" : "localhost",
    "port" : 8080,
    "path" : ""
}

conn_str = "http://" + ("%(user)s:%(pass)s@" % conn_settings if(conn_settings.get("user", "")) else "") + "%(host)s:%(port)d%(path)s" % conn_settings
print "Connecting using: %s" % conn_str

client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(conn_str)

print "You can call this"
print client.system.listMethods()

print "Trying Query"
print client.ContentAPI.queryResult("1376")
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I've worked it out:

    from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy
    url = "https://username:password@server:port/xplrpc"
    s = ServerProxy(url)
    print s.ContentAPI.queryResult("1376")